# exec.Cmd is driving me insane

Tags: bash, go, command-line, command-line-arguments

The story is this: I have a program named coletorbeat that needs a large argument to run. This argument is built on a few parameters. I built a second program called bootstrapper that takes these parameters, builds the long argument required by coletorbeat and should then run coletorbeat, feeding it the long argument.
I have tried multiple ways, with escaped quotes, backticks, and so on. But for some reason, the program is called and as if no argument had been passed at all. I don't even have an error message.
I'll post the code below, any help is very much appreciated.

Fields like coletorbeat.ip=%v should appear on the command line inside quotes or back-ticks, preceded by the flag -E.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "os"
    "os/exec"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    if len(os.Args) < 8 {
        fmt.Printf("%v arguments were given. 8 needed to work", len(os.Args))
        return
    }
    // Parâmetros devem ser passados na ordem: ip, porta, data_inicio, data_fim, tipo_equipamento, versao, nivel, instituicao
    //There can`t be empty spaces on any of the strings inside the Args. We gotta do some prevention in case it happens here.

    flag := "-E"
    Arg1 := fmt.Sprintf("`coletorbeat.ip=%v`", os.Args[1])
    Arg2 := fmt.Sprintf("`coletorbeat.porta=%v`", os.Args[2])
    Arg3 := fmt.Sprintf("`coletorbeat.dataInicio=%v`", os.Args[3])
    Arg4 := fmt.Sprintf("`coletorbeat.dataFim=%v`", os.Args[4])
    Arg5 := fmt.Sprintf("`coletorbeat.tipoEquipamento=%v`", os.Args[5])
    Arg6 := fmt.Sprintf("`coletorbeat.versao=%v`", os.Args[6])
    Arg7 := fmt.Sprintf("`coletorbeat.nivel=%v`", os.Args[7])
    Arg8 := fmt.Sprintf("`coletorbeat.instituicao=%v`", os.Args[8])
    Arg9 := fmt.Sprintf("`output.elasticsearch.index=collectorbeat-%v-%v-%v-%v`", os.Args[8], os.Args[5], time.Now().Format("20060201"), os.Args[1])

    commandToExecute := &exec.Cmd{
        Path: "coletorbeat",
        Args: []string{"./", flag, Arg1, flag, Arg2, flag, Arg3, flag, Arg4, flag, Arg5, flag, Arg6, flag, Arg7, flag, Arg8, flag, Arg9},       
        Stdout: os.Stdout,
        Stderr: os.Stdout,
    }
    fmt.Println(commandToExecute.Args)
    fmt.Println("Copy the code")
    if err := commandToExecute.Run(); err != nil {
        fmt.Println("error caught on Bootstrapper")
        fmt.Println("Error: ", err)
    }
}
```

Comment: Do not use quotes even if args contain spaces. You are preparing args to be called via a shell. You do not need the when executing the program directly.

Comment: A couple of things to try: 1) Use a single quote instead of a back-tick.  2) Make one long string that's all of the arguments as if you typed it on bash command line, and just pass that single string as a single arg. 3) make a new program that just reads the args and logs them out, substitute it for coletorbeat and see if you _are_ getting the args you expect. 4) Make the -E part of the arg, instead of being their own e.g. "-E 'coletorbeat.ip=%v'"

Comment: It's quite simple, really: since there is no shell involved, the arguments passed to exec.Command (or, in this case, assigned to Cmd.Args) become os.Args in the invoked program, _without any changes_. So unless coletorbeat expects iteral quotes (which would be quite unusual), remove them all.

Comment: Also, since you are building Cmd by hand you must use the program name ("coletorbeat") as the first element of Args: `Args: []string{"coletorbeat", "./" ...}`. I strongly suggest you use exec.Command instead.

Answer (score 0):

Weirdly enough, the below solution solved the problem:

```
func main() {
    if len(os.Args) < 8 {
        fmt.Printf("%v arguments were given. 8 needed to work", len(os.Args))
        return
    }

    cmd := exec.Command("full/canonical/executable/file/path", "-E", fmt.Sprintf("\"coletorbeat.ip=%v\"", os.Args[1]), "-E", fmt.Sprintf("\"coletorbeat.porta=%v\"", os.Args[2]), "-E", fmt.Sprintf("\"coletorbeat.dataInicio=%v\"", os.Args[3]), "-E", fmt.Sprintf("\"coletorbeat.dataFim=%v\"", os.Args[4]), "-E", fmt.Sprintf("\"coletorbeat.tipoEquipamento=%v\"", os.Args[5]), "-E", fmt.Sprintf("\"coletorbeat.versao=%v\"", os.Args[6]), "-E", fmt.Sprintf("\"coletorbeat.nivel=%v\"", os.Args[7]), "-E", fmt.Sprintf("\"coletorbeat.instituicao=%v\"", os.Args[8]), "-E", fmt.Sprintf("\"output.elasticsearch.index=collectorbeat-%v-%v-%v-%v\"", os.Args[8], os.Args[5], time.Now().Format("20060201"), os.Args[1]))

    fmt.Println(cmd.Args)

    var out bytes.Buffer
    var stderr bytes.Buffer
    cmd.Stdout = &out
    cmd.Stderr = &stderr
    err := cmd.Run()
    fmt.Println(fmt.Sprint(err) + ": " + out.String())
}
```